# GCC : Return statement from a void function in C

Tags: c, gcc, void

`void bar()` means that `bar` returns nothing. I'm curious to know, If `void` returns nothing, then **why doesn't the compiler(GCC) gives any warnings or errors, when compiling following program?**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo (void)
{
        printf("In foo() function\n");
}

void bar (void)
{
        printf("In bar() function\n");
        return foo(); // Note this return statement.
}

int main (void)
{
        bar();
        return 0;
}
```

I have compiled using `gcc -Wall myprog.c`, and it's working fine.

Comment: Because even though it returns nothing you can still use `return` to interrupt the function.

Comment: @Havenard: Your comment does not make sense.

Comment: Which version of gcc do you use? Versions before 5 default to non-standard C90 which is outdated since 18 years. Use a more recent version or speficy standard C, i.e. C11 - at least C99.

Comment: The code is accepted as an extension (it is valid in C++), and no warning is printed in non-pedantic mode because it doesn't seem likely to cause any issue: you are using consistent return types for foo and bar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This construct has been disallowed in C99:

> `return` without expression not permitted in function that returns a value (and vice versa)

Compiling with proper version of standard compliance turned on [produces](http://ideone.com/JlkNRw) an appropriate error:

> prog.c:11:16: error: ISO C forbids ‘return’ with expression, in function returning void [-Werror=pedantic]
>
> ```
> return foo(); // Note this return statement.
>        ^~~~~
> ```

As for the reason why this worked with older versions of C, the original K&R lacked `void` keyword, so programmers who wanted to make it explicit that the function does not return anything were using preprocessor with `#define VOID int` or something similar. Of course, this "poor man's `void`" allowed returning an `int` value, so the code from your post would perfectly compile. My guess is that the authors of earlier versions of the standard were reluctant to plug this hole, because it would be a breaking change.